# Only vertical line in a square

Tags: html, css

I need only horizontal line in a square, I tried in this way but in my case I need only horizontal line on top ,

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: gray;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, black, black), linear-gradient(to right, red, transparent), linear-gradient(to right, black, black), linear-gradient(to bottom, red, transparent);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 1px 100%, 1px 100%, 100% 1px, 100% 1px;
  background-position: 20px 0px, 21px 0px, 0px 10px, 0px 11px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 3px red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

below is my working fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/uXbn6/4322/

Comment: *"I need only horizontal line [...] but in my case I need only vertical line"* - sorry, what? You might want to reword your question. Also, a fiddle might be helpful.

Comment: Please be more specific and clear with the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
div {
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid;
    background-color: gray;
    background-image: 
        linear-gradient(to bottom, black, black), 
        linear-gradient(to right, red, transparent), 
        linear-gradient(to right, black, black),   
        linear-gradient(to bottom, red, transparent);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 1px 100%, 1px 100%, 100% 1px, 100% 1px;
    background-position: 0px 10px, 0px 11px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 3px red;
 }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uXbn6/4324/)